# Why does selenium display the same page even after going to next page?

Tags: python, selenium, zillow

I'm trying to scrape rental listing data on Zillow. Specifically, I want the link, price, and address of each property. However, after scraping the first page successfully and clicking the next arrow button, it just displays the same listings even though the page shows I'm on page 2, 3, etc. How do I get the next page(s) listings? The project is supposed to use BeautifulSoup and Selenium, but after some research it looks like using only selenium is the easiest way to do this since Zillow uses lazy-loading.

main.py code:

```
DRIVER_PATH = "D:\chromedriver.exe"
FORM_URL = "HIDDEN"
WEBPAGE = "https://www.zillow.com/toronto-on/rentals/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-79.40771727189582%2C%22east%22%3A-79.35750631913703%2C%22south%22%3A43.639155005365474%2C%22north%22%3A43.66405824004801%7D%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A15%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A792680%2C%22regionType%22%3A6%7D%5D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22fore%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22ah%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22sort%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22days%22%7D%2C%22auc%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22nc%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fr%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22sf%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22tow%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fsbo%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22cmsn%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fsba%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%7D"

data_entry = DataEntry(DRIVER_PATH)

# Opens the webpage and gets count of total pages via self.next_btns_len)
data_entry.open_webpage(WEBPAGE)
# n is the iterator for the number of pages on the site.
n = 1

# Scrapes link, price, address data, adds each to a specified class list, and then goes to next page.
while n < (data_entry.next_btns_len + 1):
    # Scrapes one page of data and adds data to list in class object
    data_entry.scrape_data()
    # Goes to next page for scraping
    sleep(5)
    data_entry.next_page()
    n += 1
```

enter_data.py code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep


class DataEntry:
    """Enters the data from soup into Google Form"""
    def __init__(self, driver_path):
        # Options keeps the browser open after execution.
        self.chrome_options = Options()
        self.chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, chrome_options=self.chrome_options)
        self.links = []
        self.prices = []
        self.addresses = []
        self.next_btns_len = 0

    def open_webpage(self, webpage):
        # Opens desired webpage and gives two seconds to load
        self.driver.get(webpage)
        sleep(2)

        # Gets total page numbers for main.py while loop
        page_nums = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.Text-c11n-8-69-2__sc-aiai24-0.gCvDSp')
        self.next_btns_len = int(page_nums.text.split()[3])

    def scrape_data(self):
        # Scrolls to each listing to make it visible to Selenium.
        n = 1
        while n < 41:
            listing = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[{n}]')
            self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", listing)
            print(n)
            n += 1

        # todo: Create a list of links for all the listings you scraped.
        links = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".list-card-info .list-card-link")
        link_list = [link.get_attribute("href") for link in links]
        # The if statement is to check if the DOM class name has changed, which produces an empty list.
        # If the list is empty, then changes the css_selector. The website alternates between two.
        if len(link_list) == 0:
            links = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".StyledPropertyCardDataArea-c11n-8-69-2__sc-yipmu-0.dZxoFm.property-card-link")
            link_list = [link.get_attribute("href") for link in links]
        self.links.extend(link_list)
        print(len(self.links))
        print(self.links)
        # todo: Create a list of prices for all the listings you scraped. 
        prices = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".list-card-price")
        price_list = [price.text for price in prices]
        if len(price_list) == 0:
            prices = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".StyledPropertyCardDataArea-c11n-8-69-2__sc-yipmu-0.kJFQQX")
            price_list = [price.text for price in prices]
        split_price_list = [price.split() for price in price_list]
        final_price_list = [price[0].strip("C+/mo") for price in split_price_list]
        self.prices.extend(final_price_list)
        print(len(self.prices))
        print(self.prices)
        # todo: Create a list of addresses for all the listings you scraped. 
        addresses = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".list-card-addr")
        address_list = [address.text for address in addresses]
        if len(address_list) == 0:
            addresses = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".StyledPropertyCardDataArea-c11n-8-69-2__sc-yipmu-0.dZxoFm.property-card-link address")
            address_list = [address.text for address in addresses]
        self.addresses.extend(address_list)
        print(len(self.addresses))
        print(self.addresses)

    def next_page(self):
        # Clicks the next arrow and waits 2 seconds for page to load
        next_arrow = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Next page']")
        next_arrow.click()
        sleep(5)

    def close_webpage(self):
        self.driver.quit()

    def enter_data(self, form_url, address, rent, link):
        # Opens the Google Form and waits 3 seconds to load.
        self.driver.get(form_url)
        sleep(2)

        # Enters each address, rent, and link into the form. Clicks submit after.
        address_input = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div['
                                                           '2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
        address_input.send_keys(address)

        rent_input = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div['
                                                        '2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
        rent_input.send_keys(rent)

        link_input = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div['
                                                        '2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
        link_input.send_keys(link)

        submit_btn = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div['
                                                        '1]/div/span/span')
        submit_btn.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a less complex way to obtain the data you're looking for, using cloudscraper and pandas (and tqdm for convenience). You might also be in for a surprise, considering the time taken to get the data:

```
import cloudscraper
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()

df_list = []
for current_page in tqdm(range(1, 21)):
    url = f'https://www.zillow.com/search/GetSearchPageState.htm?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%22currentPage%22%3A{current_page}%7D%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-79.44174913987678%2C%22east%22%3A-79.32347445115607%2C%22south%22%3A43.57772225826024%2C%22north%22%3A43.7254027835563%7D%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A13%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A792680%2C%22regionType%22%3A6%7D%5D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22isForSaleForeclosure%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22isAllHomes%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22sortSelection%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22days%22%7D%2C%22isAuction%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22isNewConstruction%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22isForRent%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22isSingleFamily%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22isTownhouse%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22isForSaleByOwner%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22isComingSoon%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22isForSaleByAgent%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%7D&wants=%7B%22cat1%22:[%22listResults%22,%22mapResults%22]%7D&requestId=6'
    r = scraper.get(url)
    for x in r.json()['cat1']['searchResults']['listResults']:
        status = x['statusText']
        address = x['address']
        try:
            price = x['units'][0]['price']
        except Exception as e:
            price = x['price']
        if not 'https://www.' in x['detailUrl']:
            url = 'https://zillow.com' + x['detailUrl']
        else:
            url = x['detailUrl']
        df_list.append((address, price, url))
df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns = ['Address', 'Price', 'Url'])
df.to_csv('renting_in_toronto.csv')
print(df)
```

This will save the data in a csv file, and print out:

```
100%
20/20 [00:16<00:00, 1.19it/s]
Address Price   Url
0   2221 Yonge St, Toronto, ON  C$1,900+    https://zillow.com/b/Toronto-ON/43.70606,-79.3...
1   10 Yonge St, Toronto, ON    C$2,100+    https://zillow.com/b/10-yonge-st-toronto-on-BM...
2   924 Avenue Rd, Toronto, ON M5P 2K6  C$1,895/mo  https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/924-Avenue-...
3   797 Don Mills Rd, Toronto, ON   C$1,850+    https://zillow.com/b/Toronto-ON/43.71951,-79.3...
4   15 Queens Quay E, Toronto, ON   C$2,700+    https://zillow.com/b/Toronto-ON/43.64202,-79.3...
... ... ...
```

You can install the packages with `pip install cloudscraper` & `pip install tqdm`. The urls accessed are visible in Dev Tools, Network tab, and are providing JSON data which is loaded by Javascript into page.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm a Python beginner and I'm trying to understand how each piece works. How come when I try to print the r.json() I get this exception: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0). Oddly enough, I can still see the DOM results even when getting that exception. How does that work?

Comment: You get thast error when using cloudscraper? At which point in code?

Comment: If I try to do print(r.json()) I get that error. Also, if I comment out everything after address = x['address'] and try to print(address), I get those errors.

Comment: I just ran it again. It works, plain and simple. What else are you doing apart from the code in my answer? Import *just* what is in the code above. Restart your system or deactivate/activate your virtual environment. It works, it prints out the dataframe, and if you want, you can print out the full json object as well.

Comment: Thank you. Your code works. I'm just trying to break it down to see how each part works. For example, when I write out the following code I get the errors mentioned before:

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
response = scraper.get(URL)
print(response.json())

Comment: update your packages do `pip install -U requests`, then `pip install-U cloudscraper`. Not sure what's going on on your system. How is that `URL` defined? try scraper.get(actual_url), see what happens. What python version are you using? Does it support f-strings?